# Is it possible to have URL parameters without question marks, using Jekyll on Github Pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have this URL now:

http://unav-go.github.io/?p=37.1966,-3.6245

I would like to have a nice URL like this:

http://unav-go.github.io/37.1966/-3.6245

I was reading the Jekyll documentation, but I didn't find how to do this. Is this possible? Thanks in advance |o/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. `http://domain.tld/path/` is an url pointing to `http://domain.tld/path/index.html` or whatever you've set your index page to be in your server configuration.

`http://domain.tld/path?param=value` is an url (always pointing to `http://domain.tld/path/index.html`) with parameters that are used server side (as your site is static, they are not used server side) or client side by javascript (it's how you use them to generate your gmap marker).

Doing `http://domain.tld/path/value` suppose that you can process the url server side to transform it back to `http://domain.tld/path?param=value`. But it's not possible in static world.

Answer (score 1):

Doing:

```
http://unav-go.github.io/37.1966/-3.6245
```

would just direct to another location in your Jekyll site.

So, I don't recommend doing that. It's possible to do that but you will be redirecting and you would be creating a lot of links to redirect to the proper locations since the app is utilizing the parameters in the URL.

I'd suggest going for the former.

```
http://unav-go.github.io/?p=37.1966,-3.6245
```